# How to define key and value of go struct

Tags: go, struct

What is the idiomatic way to write a Golang struct when the left side value is has the same name as the right side value? Example:

```
type Something struct {
  Names Names
}

type Names struct {
  ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's it. There's nothing un-idiomatic about a field name being the same as its type name. What is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Giving the name to a field that is identical to its type name is perfectly valid in Go, and is often used.

Some examples from the standard library:

Fields of [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request):

```
URL      *url.URL
Header   Header
Response *Response
```

Fields of [`http.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server):

```
Handler Handler
```

Fields of [`png.Encoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/png/#Encoder):

```
CompressionLevel CompressionLevel
```

This doesn't cause confusion nor ambiguity, because referring to a struct variable's fields is `varName.FieldName` (and this always denotes the field and not its type), and referring to the type is `declaringPackage.TypeName`. It's not the same even if the type is declared in the same package (and hence `declaringPackage` is "missing"), because `varName` cannot be "empty".